# PHP Soapclient returns object has no property

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

When sending a request from my PHP soapclient as described below, I get:

```
[getInterestAndExchangeRates failed: Please check inparameters in Xxx].
```

I suspect that it is the [$response] line that has wrong syntax. More specific the [$searchRequestParameters]. I have checked that all the content in the array is in the correct order.

**Question:**

Is there something wrong with below code syntax?

I have followed following instructions:

https://swea.riksbank.se/sweaWS/docs/api/call/getInterestAndExchangeRates.htm

```
<?php

/**
 * A soapclient request to Swedish Central bank, API.
 */

$client = new SoapClient("https://swea.riksbank.se/sweaWS/wsdl/sweaWS_ssl.wsdl");

$searchGroupSeries = array(
    "groupid"  => 2,
    "seriesid" => "SECBREPOEFF"
);


$searchRequestParameters = array (
    "aggregateMethod"   => "W",
    "avg"               => true,
    "datefrom"          => "2018-01-01",
    "dateto"            => "2019-01-01",
    "languageid"        => "en",
    "max"               => true,
    "min"               => false,
    "searchGroupSeries" => $searchGroupSeries,
    "ultimo"            => false
);

// Test 1 (pointing out above array, does not work):    
$response = $client->__soapCall("getInterestAndExchangeRates", $searchRequestParameters);

// Test 2 (wrap in above array inside another array, does not work):
// $response = $client->__soapCall('getInterestAndExchangeRates', array('searchRequestParameters' => $searchRequestParameters));

var_dump($response);
```

**Error:**

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [soap:Server] getInterestAndExchangeRates failed: Please check inparameters in [path]_(does_not_work).php:22
Stack trace:
#0 [path]_(does_not_work).php(22): SoapClient->__soapCall('getInterestAndE...', Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in [path]_(does_not_work).php on line 22
```

Comment: `array($searchRequestParameters)` why? Why not `$searchRequestParameters`?

Comment: @Rahul Your comment makes sense. I changed the question and will update the error message.

Comment: @Rahul seems that sometimes it has to wrapped into an array: https://www.php.net/manual/en/soapclient.soapcall.php